# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JLabel.getY()"

Tags: java

The full error

```
   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JLabel.getY()" because "this.animal.animals[save.Data.selectedAnimal]" is null
    at AnimatorHandler.FishAnimation.actionPerformed(FishAnimation.java:26)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:311)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:243)
```

I don't understand why when I try to move a method to another class to clean the code, it gives me this error.

Here it is the class in witch the method works:

```
   package main;

   import java.awt.Dimension;
   import java.awt.Graphics;
   import java.awt.Graphics2D;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.Random;
   
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;
   import javax.swing.Timer;

   import AnimatorHandler.FishAnimation;
   import data.*;
   import save.Data;

   public class Screen extends JPanel{
    
    Resources res = new Resources();
    Background background = new Background();
    Ground ground = new Ground();
    Animal animal = new Animal(null, null, 0, null, 0, 0);
    FishAnimation fA = new FishAnimation();
    
    int screenSizeX = 1099;
    int screenSizeY = 735;
    Timer timer;
    
    void createWindow() throws IOException {
        
        //CREATION OF THE RESOURCES
        background.createBackground();
        ground.createGround();
        animal.createAnimal();
        
        //SETTING OF THE LAYEREDPANE
        JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.setBounds(0, 0, screenSizeX, screenSizeY);
        layeredPane.add(background.background[Data.selectedBackground], Integer.valueOf(0));
        layeredPane.add(ground.ground[Data.selectedGround], Integer.valueOf(1));
        layeredPane.add(animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal], Integer.valueOf(2));
        layeredPane.add(animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal+1], Integer.valueOf(2));
           
        //SETTING OF THE FRAME
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Happy Aquarium");
        frame.add(layeredPane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(screenSizeX, screenSizeY));
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        //ANIMATION
        fA.action();
    }
    /* If I put the code here the program give me no problem
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
    */
   }
```

Here it is the new Class:

```
   package AnimatorHandler;

   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

   import javax.swing.Timer;

   import data.Animal;
   import save.Data;

   public class FishAnimation implements ActionListener{
    
    Animal animal = new Animal(null, null, 0, null, 0, 0);
    Timer timer;
    
    public void action() {
          timer = new Timer(1, this);
          timer.start();
          
          
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal].getY() >= 260 || animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal].getY()<-300) {
            
            animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal].setYVelocity(animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal].getYVelocity() * -1);
        }
        
        if(animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal].getX() >= 456 || animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal].getX()<-456) {
            
            animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal].setXVelocity(animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal].getXVelocity() * -1);
            
        }
        animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal].setBounds(animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal].getX() + animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal].getXVelocity(), animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal].getY() + animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal].getYVelocity(), 1083, 696);

        if(animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getY() >= 260 || animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getY()<-300) {
            
            animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal+1].setYVelocity(animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getYVelocity() * -1);
        }
        
        if(animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getX() >= 456 || animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getX()<-456) {

            animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal+1].setXVelocity(animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getXVelocity() * -1);
            
        }
        animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal+1].setBounds(animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getX() + animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getXVelocity(), animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getY() + animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getYVelocity(), 1083, 696);
        
        
    }
    
    
   }
```

Animal Class:

```
   package data;

   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.Scanner;

   import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
   import javax.swing.JLabel;

   import main.Resources;

   public class Animal {
    
    Resources res = new Resources();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String name;
    String description; 
    double price;
    JLabel label;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int xVelocity = 1;
    int yVelocity = 1;
    public JLabel[] animals = new JLabel[2];
    public Animal[] animali = new Animal[2];

    public int getXVelocity() {
        return xVelocity;
    }
    public void setXVelocity(int xVelocity) {
        this.xVelocity = xVelocity;
    }
    public int getYVelocity() {
        return yVelocity;
    }
    public void setYVelocity(int yVelocity) {
        this.yVelocity = yVelocity;
    }
    

    
    public void xyRandomizer() {
        
        x = (int) (Math.random()*((0 + 912)-456));
        y = (int) (Math.random()*((0 + 560)-300)) ;
    }
    public void xyVelocityChooser() {
        
        xVelocity = (int) (Math.random()*((0 + 4)-2));
        yVelocity = (int) (Math.random()*((0 + 4)-2));
        if (xVelocity == 0) {
            xVelocity = (int) (Math.random()*((0 + 4)-2));
            xVelocity++;
        }
        if (yVelocity == 0) {
            yVelocity = (int) (Math.random()*((0 + 4)-2));
            yVelocity++;
        }
    }
    
    
    
    public void createAnimal() throws IOException {
        res.addAnimal();
        
        //CREATING THE FISHES
        JLabel fish_ph = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(res.animal[0]));
        xyRandomizer();
        xyVelocityChooser();
        fish_ph.setBounds(x,y,1083,696);
        fish_ph.setLayout(null);
        Animal fishph = new Animal("PlaceHolder1", "Is just a PlaceHolder", 0.5, fish_ph, xVelocity, yVelocity);
        animals[0] = fish_ph;
        animali[0] = fishph;
        
        JLabel fish_r_ph = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(res.animal[1]));
        xyRandomizer();
        xyVelocityChooser();
        fish_r_ph.setBounds(x,y,1083,696);
        fish_ph.setLayout(null);
        Animal fishph1 = new Animal("PlaceHolder2", "Is just a second PlaceHolder", 0.5, fish_ph, xVelocity, yVelocity);
        animals[1] = fish_r_ph;
        animali[1] = fishph1;
        
        
    }
    
    public String getAnimalName() throws IOException {
        createAnimal();
        int y=0;
        for(Animal i : animali) {
            
            System.out.println(y + ")" + i.name);
            y++;
        }
        return "";
        
    }
    
    public Animal(String name, String description, double price, JLabel label, int xVelocity, int yVelocity){
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.label = label;
        this.xVelocity = xVelocity;
        this.yVelocity = yVelocity;
    }
}
```

Resources Class:

```
   package main;

   import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;

   import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

   public class Resources {
    
    
    public BufferedImage[] background = new BufferedImage[2];
    public BufferedImage[] ground = new BufferedImage[2];
    public BufferedImage[] animal = new BufferedImage[2];
    
    public void addBackground() throws IOException {
        
        //ASSIGNING OF THE RESOURCES FROM THE TANK FOLDER
        BufferedImage tank_ph = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/tank/tank_placeholder.png"));
        BufferedImage tank_p_ph = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/tank/tank_purple_placeholder.png"));
        background[0] = tank_ph;
        background[1] = tank_p_ph;
    }
    public void addGround() throws IOException {
        
        //ASSIGNING OF THE RESOURCES FROM THE TERRAINS FOLDER
        BufferedImage terrain_ph = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/terrains/terrain_placeholder.png"));
        ground[0] = terrain_ph;
    }
    public void addAnimal() throws IOException {
        
        //ASSIGNING OF THE RESOURCES FROM THE FISH FOLDER
        BufferedImage fish_ph = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/fish/PH/place_holder_left_1.png"));
        animal[0] = fish_ph;
        BufferedImage fish_r_ph = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/fish/PHR/place_holder_3.png"));
        animal[1] = fish_r_ph;
    }
   }
```

I tried searching in internet but found nothing. The only thing I did was cleaning the code, thats all.

The thing that is supposed to to is make the fish move on the tank. and I wanted to Take the method out of the Screen class to organize the animation and not make a mess in the screen class

Comment: Most likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it, but I’m afraid your code is a bit convoluted and difficult to follow.  Apparently the `animals` array is initialized in `createAnimal`, which is called from two places.  One of those places is… the getAnimalName method?  (Why does the Animal class contain an `animals` array in the first place?)

Comment: @VGR The `createAnimal` in the getAnimalName method is not used (I just used it once for debugging. The `animals` array in the Animal class because it function as a list witch contain all of the animal I create and add

Comment: *I tried searching in internet but found nothing.* - you have to be joking. This is the most commonly asked question. You have a null variable. The stack trace tells you which statement is causing the problem. So figure out which variable is null and then fix the problem.